# problems using nancy to handle requests for subfolder in mvc 3 app

Tags: asp.net, nancy

I am trying to set up nancy to handle requests to the /api url in my mvc 3 app.

I have set up 2 nancy routes in my ApiModule

Get["/"] = _ => "Hello"; // returns "Hello" as expected

Get["/newsletter/signup"] = _ => "ddddd"; // returns a asp.net 404. Not expected.

/newsletter/signup/test returns a nancy 404.

I have checked config and restarted the app many times but I can't get it to work correctly.

EDIT: Here is the involved code and configuration

```
public class ApiModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly INewsletterSubscriberRepository _newsletterSubscriberRepository;

    public ApiModule(INewsletterSubscriberRepository newsletterSubscriberRepository) : base("/api")
    {
        _newsletterSubscriberRepository = newsletterSubscriberRepository;


        Get["/newsletter/signup"] = _ => "ddddd";

        Get["/"] = _ => "Hello";
    }
}
```

base.web.config

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="api/*" />
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="api/*" />
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The I created a api folder and put this web.config there

```
    <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <clear/>
      <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should all be covered in the Wiki:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-asp.net

Comment: I have followed every step in the 'Adding Nancy to an existing site' section. It works for the '/' path but not the '/newsletter/signup' path

Comment: @TT can you add your web.config setup and the module class to the question then please, there's obviously something wrong with how you'r e referring to the paths if you're getting a Nancy 404.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I created an MVC 4.0 website:

This problem is the default MVC template sets up a route to `"api/{controller}/{id}"` in your `WebAPIConfig.cs` file.

You need to delete/change this route or it will steal all requests going to `/api/xxxx`

Change this file so that it looks like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{

}
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It throws 404 (NotFound) because you do not have a route that can accept "/newsletter/signup/test".

To correct this, instead of

```
Get["/newsletter/signup"]
```

replace it with

```
Get["/newsletter/signup/{param}"]
```

This route has a Capture Segment {param} that captures whatever is passed into the given segment of the requested URL and then passes it into the Action of the route. You can refer to this [guide](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes) for more information about defining routes in Nancy.